# Performance decrease after each batch processed by a background job

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, batch-processing

I noticed that my background job performing worse after each batch. Basically, job takes huge csv file and then updates relevant records in database in batches of 250 records. After each batch I am re-creating db context to keep ObjectContext tidy, but that doesn't help and it looks like just everything is getting slower after each batch. My job does:

1. Read 250 records from file
2. Create DbContext
3. Then for each record
4. Get corresponding entity from DB
5. Update properties (reflection)
6. When 250 records processed - SaveChanges

So when job starts, it takes ~170ms for 4. and ~6ms for 5.

After 50 batches, it takes ~430ms for 4. and **~500ms** for 5.

Can someone explain please what is happening here?

**Update.**
As it turned out it wasn't hangfire fault - so I removed all references to hangfire.

The problem seems to be with DbContext, despite I am recreating DbContext processing still takes longer after each batch. Also I missed one thing from 5. - call to `dbContext.Entry(entity).Property("Guid").IsModified = false` that takes longer each time:

```
//for each 250 items
var dbContext = new MyDbContext();

dbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

foreach (var item in items)
{
    var entity = dbContext.MyItems
        .Include(x => x.SomeProp) // lots of these
        .FirstOrDefault(BuildFilterFrom(item)); //after each batch this taking longer (starting from 170ms and then after 50 batches it takes 430ms)

    //set entity propties from item
    //...

    dbContext.Entry(entity).Property("Guid").IsModified = false //after each batch this also taking longer (starting from 6ms and then after 50 batches it takes 500ms)
}
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: can you provide the code snippe performing the six steps?

Comment: Check the SQL script that gets generated by this process. I had something similar recently where Entity Framework created horrible SQL (not really its fault), and because I was executing it many many times, it was blowing up the query optimizer. Since you're not doing a bulk grab, that reduces the chances of my scenario applying, but I would still look at the database connection.

Comment: What do system resources look like while this is running (potential memory leak)?

Comment: @Nico I updated my question with more details.

Comment: @krillgar thanks for your comment, I think you might be right - it must be something wrong with by db calls..

Answer (score 1):

From your update, I think the best bet you would have is to ignore the Guid property when you change them. You should be able to add a `.Where()` to your collection of properties to eliminate them with that name. That way you save the microseconds of setting the property, and also of changing the `IsModified` property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this will certainly give me some improvements however there is still and issue with FirstOrDefault call. I started to rework my code to use Update from EntityFramework.Extended (to avoid loading entities), however I'd like to understand why FirstOrDefault call keeps slowing down.

Comment: It could have to do with the filter that you build, and how many related objects are that you pull back. As I said in my comment on the question, take a look at the SQL that gets generated. You might be better off grabbing all of your objects in a single call to the database, you might not be. With these large bulk processes, you're finally into the territory where checking with SQL Server Profiler and "Include Actual Execution Plan" are a **huge** benefit.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to give any info from the information you have posted .Definitely hangfire job does not get tired but depending on the type of job and recurrence,exceptions etc ,hangfire serializes the data and keeps it in the database and fetches it again from DB.

Are you following the best practices described here http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/best-practices.html . You can also use logging to your  understand which part of the job is taking time,make use of trace loglevel to understand if hangfire is causing the issue

http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/configuring-logging.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, that wasn't hangfire fault. Something is wrong with dbcontext or my calls to db.